# Is there a simple way to clear "documents & data" + "other" from iPhone while running iOS 10 beta?

Tags: iphone, ios, beta-seed-program

I am running the iOS 10 beta and there is roughly 6GB on my iPhone 6s that is currently documents & data and other. I want to get rid of it the simplest way possible. Under non-beta I could do a backup and restore. In beta, it doesn't seem as simple to restore the phone and free up all that space. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a backup using iTunes, then going to settings on the iPhone and erasing everything. Then restore from the backup.

Comment: Thanks. I know of that method and it works when not in beta but I end up having to input passwords and download apps again, etc. I was looking for a simple way to see and erase those docs & other.